# Как сохранить блок <head> после очистки html через htmlpurifilter?

Tags: php

Очищаю html через htmlpurifilter но удаляет блок  в котором находятся , мне стили необходимо сохранить. Как это сделать?

Comment: попробуй оформить вопрос на понятном языке

Comment: А что не поонятно? Я пытаюсь очистить html от мусора используя htmlpurifilter. Он очищает блок head, но мне надо его сохранить. Вроде понятно

Comment: Укажи в параметрах разрешенные тэги (http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Allowed)

Comment: @Loligan А ты прочитай свой вопрос, я вижу там что-то нечеткое и много неуважения к участникам сообщества. `Азазчем песат правельноеслиэтонеэкзамен?`

Comment: @ilyaplot к сожалению он head и style теги не хочет принимать

Comment: @Loligan http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.ConvertDocumentToFragment Поставьте этот параметр в false

Comment: Ну нет так нет. Можно подумать оно мне надо...

Comment: @ilyaplot использовал чуть ли не сразу. Не работает также

Comment: @Loligan А с какой целью вы прогоняете через htmlpurifilter страницу полностью? Может вы просто стреляете пушкой по воробьям? Инструмент предназначен для преобразования текста со вставками html, а не для обработки целых страниц.